# Want to populate sets of records from sales table by joining deliveries

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am a novice to MySQL

I have a database where I want to populate sets of records from 'sales' table where condition is sales is not delivered by comparing with 'deliveries' table of 'deliveries.reference_no'.

Both Tables has reference_no in common which is the invoice ref number.

I tried few SQL and got all common filed as it is and tried this one below but its displaying  #1052 - Column 'date' in field list is ambiguous.

```
SELECT sales.id AS sid, date, reference_no, biller_name, customer_name, total_tax, total_tax2, total, internal_note FROM sales LEFT JOIN deliveries ON (sales.reference_no = deliveries.reference_no)
```

For more information below is my two table schema

Sales

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `reference_no` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `warehouse_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `biller_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `biller_name` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_name` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `note` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `internal_note` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_total` decimal(25,2) NOT NULL,
  `total_tax` decimal(25,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` decimal(25,2) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `in_type` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_tax2` decimal(25,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tax_rate2_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_discount` decimal(25,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `paid_by` varchar(55) DEFAULT 'cash',
  `count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping` decimal(25,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `pos` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `paid` decimal(25,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cc_no` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cc_holder` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cheque_no` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

Deliveries

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `deliveries` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `reference_no` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `customer` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `note` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Currently I have a CI program and I am doing like this no Luck what I want to populate

CI PHP

```
     function getdatatableajax()
   {
        if($this->input->get('search_term')) { $search_term = $this->input->get('search_term'); } else { $search_term = false;}

       $this->load->library('datatables');
       $this->datatables
            ->select("sales.id as sid, date, reference_no, biller_name, customer_name, total_tax, total_tax2, total, internal_note")
            ->from('sales');

            $this->datatables->add_column("Actions", 
            "<center><a href='#' title='$2' class='tip' data-html='true'><i class='icon-folder-close'></i></a> <a href='#' onClick=\"MyWindow=window.open('index.php?module=sales&view=view_invoice&id=$1', 'MyWindow','toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=1000,height=600'); return false;\" title='".$this->lang->line("view_invoice")."' class='tip'><i class='icon-fullscreen'></i></a> 
            <a href='index.php?module=sales&view=add_delivery&id=$1' title='".$this->lang->line("add_delivery_order")."' class='tip'><i class='icon-road'></i></a>
            <a href='index.php?module=sales&view=pdf&id=$1' title='".$this->lang->line("download_pdf")."' class='tip'><i class='icon-file'></i></a> 
            <a href='index.php?module=sales&view=email_invoice&id=$1' title='".$this->lang->line("email_invoice")."' class='tip'><i class='icon-envelope'></i></a>

            </center>", "sid, internal_note")

        ->unset_column('sid')
        ->unset_column('internal_note');

       echo $this->datatables->generate();

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, no one answered this yet?   Strange.

Your error is because the `date` field is in both tables.  You have to specify which table you want to select `date` from.  So you must write either `sales.date` or `deliveries.date`.  This goes with the rest of them, once you fix `sales.date`, your next field `reference_no` will generate the same error.  If you want data from BOTH tables you'll need to assign aliases to them as you did with the first column.

`sales.id AS sid, sales.date AS sales_date, deliveries.date AS deliveries_date` etc...

Comment: Thanks ! Lets try. I tried below things also no luck

Comment: ->select("sales.id as sid, date, reference_no, biller_name, customer_name, total_tax, total_tax2, total, internal_note")
                ->from('sales')
                ->join(deliveries, 'sales.reference_no = deliveries.reference_no', 'left');

Comment: @Anita try this:  ->select("sales.id as sid, sales.date as date, sales.reference_no as reference_no, biller_name, customer_name, total_tax, total_tax2, total, internal_note") ->from('sales') ->join(deliveries, 'sales.reference_no = deliveries.reference_no', 'left');

Comment: Hi, Now the above Query is working but its not eliminating the deliveries that have done!

Comment: Also the "Actions" vanished not coming.